# Storing English and corresponding Arabic to data base

Tags: html, forms, arabic

I want to create a simple html form. Form contain two text box. First one is for typing in English and the second for the corresponding Arabic. How can I do that?
Thanks in Advance.

I want to type both English and Arabic without changing keyboard like google translator.

Comment: Done! `<form><input><input></form>`

Comment: Show your efforts so far...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - This should be the accepted answer. It is concise and exactly answers the question.

Comment: @RoyPrins Don't know if it answers the question. Since Arabic is right-to-left, I'll probably need to add a couple of attributes for that.

Comment: I just thought of that and posted the answer. Sorry for taking advantage of your mad coding skills there ;)

Comment: @Mandy8055 I just created a form with two text input. Second text field as follow <input dir="rtl" lang="AR">

Comment: @RoyPrins  I want to type English and Arabic without changing keyboard setting. Like google translator.

Comment: What did you try to accomplish that? How does google translator do it?

Comment: @RoyPrins I want to create a dictionary like structure. We have one Arabic translator here. So we don't want google translator.

Comment: Again, what did you try to accomplish that? If you know how google does it, you know how you can do it. Or you could simply search for the solution online. I already found it. This is very low effort on your part.

Comment: @RoyPrins I saw many comments like add this tags dir="rtl" lang="AR" and add UTF-8 charset. But none of them help me

Comment: You need to rethink how you intend to use stackoverflow as a resource. This is not going to work for you.

Comment: @RoyPrins Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input>
    <input dir="rtl">
</form>
```

Comment: Its not working. I want to type with out changing my keyboard setting

Comment: Based on your detailed report on what you tried and why exactly it did not work as intended, I think we exhausted all possibilities.